# Reformatting macros so they repeat

Tags: vba, excel

I found this code elsewhere on the web and adjusted it to my needs.

I have 20000 rows to go through. How could I modify this code to repeat every 105 lines, and place the results in the same columns spaced beneath the previous. I also need the line by line data in percentage format as well.

```
Sub SumSectorWeight()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim arrProducts() As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A" & i & ":B" & i + 104)

    arrProducts = getSumOfCountArray(rng)

    Sheet2.Range("E1:E1").Value = Array("Sector", "Sector Weight")

    ' go through array and output to Sheet2
    For i = 2 To 5000 Step 105
        Sheet2.Cells(i + 2, "E").Value = arrProducts(0, i)
        Sheet2.Cells(i + 2, "F").Value = arrProducts(1, i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `repeat every 105 lines` refers to `rng`? If you found the above code and modified it this far, it will only take 15 minutes to find code that repeats per x rows just saying.

Comment: I have been writing a for loop that will enable me to automate but have been unsuccessful. I was also unable to integrate a the existing codes that would repeat x rows with my existing code. Do you have any advise findwindow?

Comment: `For i = 1 to 5000 step 105` then `Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A" & i & ":B" & i+104)`

Comment: I still don't know what's getting repeated so no advice. My point was that your code is fairly involved so if you got this far, should be quick to add one more requirement so you're probably just overthinking something/careless mistake.

Comment: Scott, Thank you for your advice. I keep getting a Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed error. Any advice?

Comment: Findwindow, I am repeating a calculation that is summing numbers in column b based upon its identifier in column a. For example, every time the value in column a is Red then the column b values are being summed. The output would be like so:                                                 Red        25         There is a window of 105 rows that are each set of data. Then the next 105 lines is another set of data, and requires the calculation to be completed again.

Comment: Why are you trying to stuff an array of two elements into a single cell (e.g. `E1` )? What is the [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac(v=vs.90).aspx) and [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) of `arrProducts` after the functions returns values? Why are you labelling column E and then putting values into columns DN:DN and DO:DO? How can you get 105 values out of A3885:B3985?

Comment: `How can you get 105 values out of A3885:B3985?` As @Jeeped points out, I am still confused on what is getting repeated.

Comment: I edited the code back to the original. The next parameters are A106:B211 and so on. What is getting repeated is the summing of the values in column B that have the same identifier in column A. I accidentally posted the version that I had used to manually update the data. Column E is the starting point, and the code posts in E, F. I need to find a way to skip G and then post in H, I skip J and so on.

Comment: Then Scott's code above should work with `i=2` instead. Did you just add a new requirement of skipping columns? XD

Comment: I added your revisions to the code and still am getting the same error. I posted the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is that the relevant code was not inside the loop.
Please see\try the below:

```
Sub SumSectorWeight()

    Dim Rng As Excel.Range
    Dim arrProducts() As String
    Dim i As Long

    Sheet2.Range("E1:E1").Value = Array("Sector", "Sector Weight")
    ' go through array and output to Sheet2
    For i = 2 To 5000 Step 105
        Set Rng = Sheet2.Range("A" & i & ":B" & i + 104)
        arrProducts = getSumOfCountArray(Rng)
        Sheet2.Cells(i + 2, "E").Value = arrProducts(0, i)
        Sheet2.Cells(i + 2, "F").Value = arrProducts(1, i)
    Next

End Sub
```